# SAP copy tables to excel wrong values

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Kindly ask for your help. I noticed that when I am trying to copy a table from SAP (from clipboard) to excel I dont get corrent the numbers in excel. For example in sap `12.000,00 EUR` pasted to excel as `12,000` which is `12`.
I copy paste in clipboard the board as I run macro behind.

```
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[45]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[4,0]").Select
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[4,0]").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

Sheets("VBRP_").Select
Range("A1").Select ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True"
```

I have also noticed that when I copy paste the table from SAP to excel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> the numbers are transfered correctly. this is not happened VIA macro.

Comment: Do you make the paste operation in code (VBA)? If yes, your used code may help. Does your macro put the area to be copied in ClipBoard? Does all the area to be copied consist in such numbers type?

Comment: I have also noticed that when I copy paste the table from SAP to excel using Ctrl + V the numbers are transfered correctly. this is not happened VIA macro.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using such a code before pasting:

```
Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
```

And after pasting:

```
Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
```

Comment: no change i have shared with you the two screenshots above.